# Integrating org-download with org-journal; images do not download

Tags: org-mode, use-package

I have org-journal entries which I'd like to link to images that are also stored alongside them in the filesystem. Ideally this would happen automatically when an image is dragged-and-dropped on the buffer.

[Org-download](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download) seems to be a good fit for this application. I can configure org-download to download and link images into regular org files, but I cannot achieve the same for org-journal files.

I received some suggestions for this [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/d28915/how_do_i_set_up_orgdownload_for_drag_and_drop/). For normal org-mode files, from my `init.el`:

```
(use-package org-download
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  ;; Add handlers for drag-and-drop when Org is loaded.
    (with-eval-after-load 'org
      (org-download-enable)))
```

I would expect this to also work for org-journal files, since they are also org-mode files. But it does not, so I've tried adjusting the configuration:

```
(use-package org-download
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :after (:any 'org 'org-journal)
  :config
    (org-download-enable))
```

This also does not work. Next I tried manually instigating with `M-: (org-download-enable)` while working on an org-journal entry. That command returns `nil` and dragging and dropping images still does not work.

At this point I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm new to configuring emacs, and likely am missing something simple. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you care about this, I found this bug and opened an issue: https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal/issues/236

Basically, org-download checks that the major mode is org-mode, but org-journal changes that to org-journal-mode.

Comment: Thank you @dangirsh, that sounds like it might be the cause of the trouble I was having!

Comment: This is now fixed! Pull org-download.

Comment: @dangrish, thank you! I checked and it is working for me now!